# Enable only pylint for Python files in Syntastic for Vim

Tags: python, vim, pylint, syntastic

I want to use "pylint" for checking my Python code in Vim. To do this, I install the Syntastic plugin, along with the "pylint" package for Ubuntu. Then I specify the checker I want to use by writing the following in my .vimrc.

```
let g:syntastic_py_checkers = ['pylint']
```

But if I write :SyntasticInfo I see that two checkers are active, "python" and "pylint", I only want pylint. So I try to disable the checkers for .py files all together.

```
let g:syntastic_py_checkers = []
```

But :SyntasticInfo still says I have two checkers active.

How do I ensure that only the pylint checker is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `syntastic_python_checkers` instead of `syntastic_py_checkers`:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = []
```

or

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint']
```

Comment: Assigning `['']` to a list of checkers doesn't do what you think it does.  Use `[]` instead.

Comment: Thanks @SatoKatsura, I edited it according to your comment